# Stable isotope sample preparation: Bone Collagen

Tags: ecology, lab-techniques, bone-biology, methods

I am performing research in which I need to extract bone collagen from the foot bones of American Beaver (*Castor canadensis*).  I have read through the literature fairly thoroughly on both the archaeological/anthropological side and the wild life side and have been finding a many tweaks to a fairly simple extraction process, but I still have a few questions.

1. When processing bone I split the bone and removed the center, which was red/ light pink, (I thought it was the marrow and wanted to make sure that I was getting collagen from only 1 part of the bone to not confuse my isotope data with varying tissues)
2. There is also some variability across papers in the time that people allow bone to demineralize in a strong acid  ranging from 20 mins to upwards of 10 hours.  Does anyone have any experience with this and size to which you ground your samples.
3. The literature has a variety of temps ranging from 58 C to 95C, it proposes to gellatinize the collagen in a weak acid over a variable number of hours (approx pH of 3), does anyone who has experience offer a temp and time that worked for them.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks